# STM32F407G-DISC1 not working if not connected to pc

Tags: embedded, stm32, stm32f4-discovery

I have a Discovery board DISC1 version (february 2016 revision).

I had programmed a Discovery board before with no issues. The ones that I more recently bought, the DISC1 version, have a strange issue: after I flash the program, if I connect them to the PC via USB (CN1), everything works fine, but if I power it up with external +5V or with the CN1 (but not from an USB port), the LD1 led start blinking, the the LD2 red led turns on, but nothing else happens. The rest of the board is off.

I stress that this never happened with the previous revision of the same board, i always powered it up via external +5V and it always worked correctly.

Does anyone have a clue why this is happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I experienced the same problem and there are two solutions to get the behavior of the old board.

1. Use the ST-Link Upgrade Utility to flash to an older version of the ST-Link v2/1. With version V2.J23.M9 it's ok. But you lose the compatibility to mbed.
2. Open the solder bridge SB19. The new board has this bridge closed, resulting in a low BOOT1-pin. When the bridge is opened the BOOT1 is pulled to Vdd. If you do not want open the solder bridge, you can use an external jumper wire from Vdd to PB2.

Comment: Thanks. After downgrading the firmware to V2.J24.M11, it now works correctly.

Comment: Does this solution work for STM32F7 boards?

Comment: Also where/how do I get an older version of ST-Link ?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same question with V2J25 firmware. And I found if I upgrade to V2J27M15 (newest version 2016/09/16), it is solved.

Answer (score 1):

I experienced the same problem. Here my solution, although not 100% satisfying:

**Set the Jumper SB10 on the bottom of the board. A solder blob will do it.**

For some reason the ST-Link/V2 part of the new STM32F407G-Disk1 board behaves different than the old version STM32F4 Discovery and prevents the STM32F4 mcu to start properly. SB10 forces the ST-link mcu in reset state.

**Warning:**
Since I only program the STM32F4 using the usb dfu programmer, i don't need the ST-Link/V2 part for programming. Don't set the Jumper, if you need the ST-Link! It will not work afterwards!

Comment: This method does not work properly. I am using an ADC at high sampling frequency, and is somehow slowed down using this method.

Answer (score 1):

Just upgrade the firmware and it works.
V2-J28-M18 (February 2017)

Jan F. Boot1 to PB2 proposal does not work. Neither does desoldering SB19.

How to upgrade:
If you use ST-Link utility, make sure you have the latest version, in the menu:
ST-LINK-> firmware update   connect.
YOU CANNOT CHOOSE the firmware version! So, if the version is a different version, download the latest version (it comes as a little program):

http://www.st.com/en/embedded-software/stsw-link007.html

was going to comment on Jan F. but I lack one karma point to be allowed to do that!